# SQL query to fetch the data from two tables with "not in" condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have 2 tables, Table1 and Table2, where 2 columns in both tables are same

update:type of Table1.col1 same as Table2.col1 and Table1.col2 same as  Table2.col2

Trying to fetch the data where table1.col1 not in table2.col1 and table1.col2 not in table2.col2, and this is my query.

```
select * from Table1 
    where Table1.col1 not in (select Table2.col1 from Table2)
      and Table1.col2 not in (select Table2.col2 from Table2)
```

would like to know any better way or is this correct ?

Comment: since the tables are the same you do not need to put the condition on both columns you just need one

Comment: @ArturUdod it will not work ... that will give you the Cartesian product except the matching values  maybe you wanted to say `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE col1 IS NULL`

Comment: @Stephan both the tables are very different except 2 columns.

Comment: i see but the combination (col1,col2) from table1 is the same with table2?

Comment: @Stephan, yes, I was wrong

Comment: Need to better define "where table1.col1 not in table2.col1 and table1.col2 not in table2.col2".  You current query treats those conditions independently.  If you want to compare them as pairs then that query is not correct.

Comment: @Blam Can you please check my answer below...is it efficient one?

Comment: The two queries are NOT the same.  I already asked you to clarify the requirement.

Comment: Blam, I updated my question and i agree with jason and Goat_CO, going with json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do the job, I ran a simple test based on your query and it doesn't produce the desired result

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL AND t2.col2 IS NULL
```

Given this

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
colA    VarChar(50),
col1    Int,
col2    Int
)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
colB    VarChar(50),
col1    Int,
col2    Int
)

INSERT Table1
VALUES ('A', 1, 1),
        ('B', 1, 2),
        ('C', 2, 1)

INSERT Table2
VALUES ('X', 1, 1),
        ('Y', 2, 1),
        ('Z', 2, 2)
```

If I understood your question, we should get this **B | 1 | 2**

Comment: That depends on the interpretation of desired result.  And only need to test for one null as if either does not match then it will not join.

Comment: @Blam yes, reason I said if I understood the question correctly, the op said `where table1.col1 not in table2.col1` **and** `table1.col2 not in table2.col21`, but his query didn't return any recordset as I expected, it's very much possible I misunderstood the question.

Comment: same scenario in my cases too , got the result ,thanks Jason

Answer (score 2):

Use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT Table1.* 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.col1 = Table2.col1
  AND Table1.col2 = Table2.col2
WHERE Table2.col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Wouldn't work better an INNER JOIN with the correct condition? LEFT JOIN performance are not the best.

Comment: If you were using '=' then yes, but with '<>' I believe the execution plan of the LEFT JOIN is simpler. Might depend on the DBMS, I've not researched it but a little.

Comment: @Wallack An inner join is not going to identify values that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

please comment, if any problem with this query:

```
select * from table1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where table2.col1 = table1.col1 and table2.col2 = table1.col2)
```