# show different data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables; each of them has a column named "color".

The colors in the first table are:

- Green
- Blue
- Red

The colors in the second table are:

- Green
- Blue

I would like a query that returns "Red", because it is not in both tables.  I've tried this:

```
select color
from tb1_color a 
join tb2_color b
on a.color = b.color
```

I can't find the proper join...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query to fetch the data from two tables with "not in" condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941982/sql-query-to-fetch-the-data-from-two-tables-with-not-in-condition)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(T1.Color,T2.Color)
FROM Table1 T1
FULL JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.Color = T2.Color
WHERE T1.Color IS NULL OR T2.Color IS NULL
```

Comment: Does mysql support full joins?

Comment: @scraatz not sure, but I saw the SQL Server tag. Should've asked for clarification

Comment: @scraatz: no, MySQL does not support full outer joins. You should tag your question with the DBMS you are using, not with an arbitrary list of DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the question. The following query returns all records from table 1 that are not in table 2. You could UNION that result with all records from table 2 that are not in table 1.

```
SELECT color FROM tb1_color tb1 WHERE tb1.color NOT IN (SELECT color FROM tb2_color)

SELECT color FROM tb1_color tb1 WHERE tb1.color NOT IN (SELECT color FROM tb2_color)
UNION ALL
SELECT color FROM tb2_color tb2 WHERE tb2.color NOT IN (SELECT color FROM tb1_color)
```

Does this return what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This query gets all the colors that are in T1 that are not in T2:

```
select color from T1 except select color from T2
```

This query gets all the colors that are in T2 that are not in T1:

```
select color from T2 except select color from T1
```

If you take the union of those two queries, you get all the colors that are not in both tables:

```
select color from T1 except select color from T2
union
(select color from T2 except select color from T1)
```

UNION and EXCEPT are standard SQL operators.